# Passing different parameter und value in TestNG without xml file

Tags: testing, junit, testng

I have test methods which should be started after TestData are set up. As the method for the set up is always the same I wanted to pass parameters to run different SQL Scripts.

```
    @Test @Parameters("sqlScript") (groups = "insert_data")
        public void testInsertData(String sqlScript) throws Exception {
            final String methodName = "testInsertData";

            scriptService.runSQL( sqlScript +".sql");
       }
```

How can I do that without using testng.xml . I know there is an option called **@Optional("CREATE TABLE T1 ....")** , but with this I just can use one parameter. What if I want to pass the method SQL for Create table for T2, T3,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @DataProvider for this instead of @Parameters.   Read more @ [Dataproviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

Comment: Your data setup is based on different sql scripts right?

Comment: yes ... so how to use just one dataprovider... can I use reflection to see where the calls came from ? The best would be to add from the caller method @Parameter and value to pass from each testmethod individual parameters....

Comment: The data provider can be used with a Method parameter.  Based on the method name, probably you can have a properties file or excel or some mapping sheet specifying name to SQL script.  The data provider based on method invoking it, would return the corresponding SQL.